# Spring file download issue

Tags: spring

I'm using spring 4.3.14

I'm facing a strange issue. I simply want to download a file by using a controller but when I use InputStreamResource downloaded file is corrupted.
This is my WebMvcConfig:

```
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 public void configureMessageConverters(List < HttpMessageConverter < ? >> converters) {
  converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
 }

}
```

I wrote the following methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public ResponseEntity < InputStreamResource > download() {
 try {
  File f = new File("/home/angelo/Scrivania/modulo.pdf");
  int dimensione = (int) f.length();
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
  HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  String mi = mimeSvc.getMimeType(fileName, is);
  MediaType mime = MediaType.parseMediaType(mi);
  respHeaders.setContentType(mime);
  respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName);
  respHeaders.setContentLength(dimensione);
  InputStreamResource result = new InputStreamResource(is);
  return new ResponseEntity < InputStreamResource > (result, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
 } catch (Exception e) {

  if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
   logger.error("Errore nel download del manuale", e);
  }
  return new ResponseEntity < InputStreamResource > (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
 }
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/download2", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public void download2() {

 try {
  File f = new File("/home/angelo/Scrivania/modulo.pdf");
  InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
  String mi = mimeSvc.getMimeType(fileName, is);
  response.setContentType(mi);
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""));
  response.setContentLength((int) f.length());
  InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
  FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
 } catch (Exception e) {
  if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
   logger.error("Errore nel download del manuale", e);
  }
  try {
   response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  } catch (IOException e1) {
   //Ignoro l'eccezione
  }
 }
}
```

By using the first method the downloaded file is corrupted. By using the second one the downloaded file is OK. I can't understand the reason
Here the logs regarding the first method:

```
2018-03-26 12:59:05,949 36704 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource> it.eng.tz.aa.suap.sue.download.manuali.controller.DownloadController.download(java.lang.String)] 2018-03-26 12:59:05,949 36704 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'downloadController' 2018-03-26 12:59:05,949 36704 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@20669e53] 2018-03-26 12:59:05,949 36704 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/download-manualistica/download/suap_sue/ME] is: -1 2018-03-26 12:59:05,949 36704 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Invoking 'it.eng.tz.aa.suap.sue.download.manuali.controller.DownloadController.download' with arguments [ME]

2018-03-26 12:59:09,325 40080 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] TRACE o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Method [it.eng.tz.aa.suap.sue.download.manuali.controller.DownloadController.download] returned [<200 OK,InputStream resource [resource loaded through InputStream],{Content-Type=[application/pdf], Content-Disposition=[form-data; name="attachment"; filename="modulo.pdf"], Content-Length=[1621137]}>] 2018-03-26 12:59:09,354 40109 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [InputStream resource [resource loaded through InputStream]] as "text/html" using [org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter@2316895c] 2018-03-26 12:59:09,354 40109 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'DownloadModulisticaSvlt': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 2018-03-26 12:59:09,354 40109 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@622b8367 2018-03-26 12:59:09,354 40109 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request 2018-03-26 12:59:09,354 40109 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'DownloadModulisticaSvlt-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/download-manualistica/download/suap_sue/ME]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[DownloadModulisticaSvlt]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[3407ms]; status=[OK]
```

Why this difference on the same file?

I always used the InputStreamResource and I had no issue.

Thank you

Angelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first download method you are using the same `FileInputStream` twice. In second, you are creating `new FileInputStream` for each use. The second approach is the right one.

Input stream is supposed to be read only once. That is why second method works and first does not. 
If input stream supports seeking you cand "rewind" the stream using `InputStream#reset` method. If rewind is supported, it will fix the issue.

```
  is.mark(0);
  is.reset();
  InputStreamResource result = new InputStreamResource(is);
```

Comment: I didn't realize i was using twice the InputStream. Thank you